# Docker ARG or ENV not working as expected in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I use Docker Toolbox for windows (for compatibility issues) and in the Dockerfile I specify an `ARG` so that I can use it when building the image with `--build-arg` command. Inside the dockerfile I also have some `COPY` commands and there I would like to use my variable but when I run docker build `--build-arg VERSION_APP=something` . it does not translate the variable . I have already used `$VERSION_APP` or `${VERSION_APP}` or `%VERSION_APP%`.

```
FROM alpine
MAINTAINER Marinos

ARG VERSION_APP


RUN apk update && apk add dos2unix

COPY script.sh /home/script.sh
RUN chmod a+x /home/script.sh

RUN dos2unix /home/script.sh 

RUN sh /home/script.sh 

COPY installation.txt /home/Desktop/${VERSION_APP}
```

**UPDATE**

It seems that you should pass the whole path to the variable you use that is how I got it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you actually use the command below then it is expected not to work because the argument called `VERSION_APP`

```
docker build --build-arg myVar=something
```

So the command should be

```
docker build --build-arg VERSION_APP=something
```

And in Dockerfile it should be `%VERSION_APP%` also you may need to use ENV like below:

```
ARG VERSION_APP
ENV VERSION_APP ${VERSION_APP}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,

sorry for the typo I wanted to write VERSION_APP and I can confirm that it still does not work. It seems that the variable is not parsed and in the path I see COPY installation.txt /home/Desktop/software/Applications/%VERSION_APP% instead of the value that I assign.

Comment: what about `$env:VERSION_APP` in Dockerfile

Comment: [Warning] One or more build-args [VERSION_APP] were not consumed

Comment: And with `%VERSION_APP%` you are getting the same message ?

Comment: I do not get the message but it does not copy the file to the path I want because it thinks that the path /home/Desktop/software/Applications/%VERSION_APP% while it should have been /home/Desktop/software/Applications/5.1

Comment: I solved it by passing the arg to an ENV.. thank you for the support

Comment: I was about to tell you the same thing :D